# How do database connections work in Google App Engine python + Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible

I have a working Python 3 app on Google App Engine (flexible) connecting to Postgres on Google Cloud SQL. I got it working by [following the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres), which at some point have you connecting via psycopg2 to a database specifier like this

```
postgresql://postgres:password@/dbname?host=/cloudsql/project:us-central1:dbhost
```

I'm trying to understand how the hostname `/cloudsql/project:us-central1:dbhost` works. Google calls this an "instance connection string" and it sure looks like it's playing the role of a regular hostname. Only with the `/` and `:` it's not a valid name for a DNS resolver.

Is Google's flexible Python environment modified somehow to support special hostnames like this? It looks like stock Python 3 and psycopg2, but maybe it's modified somehow? If so, are those modifications documented anywhere? The [docs for the Python runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) don't have anything about this.

Comment: It's a UNIX socket backed by Cloud SQL Proxy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket

Comment: oh that makes sense! So there's an actual file (socket) named `/cloudsql/project:us-central1-dbhost` on the app engine machine?

Comment: yes, you can SSH into a Flexible VM and see for yourself :)

Comment: Well thanks! You've answered my question. if you don't feel like writing up a full answer I've got some extra references, I'll write it up myself.

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer, I didn't have time to write enough for a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `host=/cloudsql/project:us-central1:dbhost` specifies the name of a directory in the filesystem. Inside that directory is a file named `.s.PGSQL.5432` which is a Unix domain socket. An instance of [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy) is listening on that Unix domain socket and forwarding database requests via TCP to the actual database server. Despite the DB connection string being `host=` it actually names a directory with a Unix socket in it; that's a feature of [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-connect.html), the Postgres connection library.

Many thanks to [Vadim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350488/vadim) for answering my question quickly in a comment, just writing up a more complete answer here for future readers.